# update query with self join

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I have a table data as below in oracle 11g,

```
 PRD_ID    PATTERN                       TXN    FLAG
 1       "UPDATE TBL1 SET TYPE='B'"      5      Y
 1       "UPDATE TBL1 SET TYPE='B'"      5      N
 2       "UPDATE TBL1 SET TYPE='B'"      6      Y
 3       "UPDATE TBL1 SET TYPE='B'"      5      Y
```

What I want to do is to remove leading and trailing double quotes from column pattern, and I could do it by trim (both '"' from (PATTERN)). My question is how could I apply it in the update statement so the table will update to below

```
 PRD_ID    PATTERN                       TXN    FLAG
   1       UPDATE TBL1 SET TYPE='B'      5      Y
   1       UPDATE TBL1 SET TYPE='B'      5      N
   2       UPDATE TBL1 SET TYPE='B'      6      Y
   3       UPDATE TBL1 SET TYPE='B'      5      Y
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
UPDATE TBL
SET PATTERN = TRIM('"' from PATTERN)
```